# How to unify access to class member when their presense is optional?

Tags: c++, std

Processing large amounts of data (gigabytes) I use indexes to data arrays. Since access to data could lead to cache inefficiency, I want to cache some data from array together with the index which gives dramatic speedup for operations through indexes.

The amount of cached data is compile-time choice which should include zero amount of cache data. I have large amount of indexes, so in this case I don’t want to pay for extra “empty” element like `std::array` does, for example.

My first idea was to introduce a dummy static `std::array` in the specialization for the struct ([demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Wzs6WdEs7)):

```
#include <array>

using data_type = int;

template<std::size_t _data_size>
struct ExtendableIndex
{
    std::size_t index;
    std::array<data_type, _data_size> data;
};

template<>
struct ExtendableIndex<0>
{
    std::size_t index;
    constexpr static std::array<data_type, 0> data;     // Dummy static object to make access to data transparent
};

constexpr std::array<data_type, 0> ExtendableIndex<0>::data;

constexpr std::size_t cache_length = 0;     // Can be set to any cache size including 0
using DefaultIndex = ExtendableIndex<cache_length>;
     
void data_user(const DefaultIndex& index)
{

    auto value = index.data.begin(); // -> this won't compile for ExtendableIndex<0> without dummy static object
}

int main()
{
    ExtendableIndex<cache_length> index_one;
    data_user(index_one);
}
```

which works fine and has the advantage of transparency for all `data_user`-type algorithms in work with `data` field regardless of the presence of real data.

*Aedoro* in his answer to my question [What is the approach to handle optional class members?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78090706/what-is-the-approach-to-handle-optional-class-members) provided much better solutions ([demo](https://godbolt.org/z/G4vefaPx8)):

```
#include <array>

using data_type = int;

template<std::size_t _data_size>
class ExtendableIndex
{
public:
    constexpr static std::size_t data_size = _data_size;

    data_type& at(std::size_t idx) { return data[idx]; }

    std::size_t index;
    std::array<data_type, _data_size> data;
};

template<>
class ExtendableIndex<0>
{
public:
    constexpr static std::size_t data_size = 0;

    data_type& at(std::size_t idx);

    std::size_t index;
};

using DefaultIndex = ExtendableIndex<0>;

class DataUser
{
public:

    void process(DefaultIndex& index)
    {
        if constexpr (DefaultIndex::data_size > 0)
        {
            // auto value = index.data[0]; // -> this fails to compile
            auto value = index.at(0); // -> but this slight workaround solves the issue, `at()` is not implemented and thats OK.
        }
    }

    template<std::size_t _data_size>
    void process_template(ExtendableIndex<_data_size>& index)
    {
        if constexpr (DefaultIndex::data_size > 0)
        {
            auto value = index.data[0]; // -> this compiles even if index.data doesn't exist when 'process' is a template
        }
    }

};

int main()
{
    DataUser r;
    ExtendableIndex<0> index_zero;

    r.process(index_zero);
    r.process_template(index_zero);

    ExtendableIndex<1> index_one;
    r.process_template(index_one);
}
```

which avoid creation of dummy static member and solves the task either with a function or with making `data_user` functions templates. I like his solution and still consider it much better than mine, but it lacks the transparency of my solution. When it comes to large `data_user` with extensive usage of `data` field, I have to write many `if constexpr` to make different code branches and this additionally hits complex conditions which rely on lazy evaluation of `||` and ‘&&` operations.

The question is, is there a third way? Namely, could this be solved transparently like in my case, without dummy static object and preferably without wrapping access to `data` field in a separate method?

I know that one of correct answers would be to make functional decomposition for `data_user` functions, extract code which works with `data` and make template with `if constexpr`, but sometimes it is hard and leads to code duplication, anyway if I want to keep lazy evaluation of `||` and ‘&&` operations.

Comment: If you need more cache friendlinees I think in this you should look at data oriented design. Like an entity/component/system. Even if you have say an optional pointer to your data that pointer will take up space in your cache lines (wich instead could have been filled with data). Not to say this is the best library but it comes with a nice introduction to ECS's : https://github.com/SanderMertens/ecs-faq

Comment: @PepijnKramer, thank you for the link, I am aware of ECS and used it many times, but how it could help here with the first statement about large size of data, caching and intent not to spend memory when it is not necessary? ECS is based on a pointer and indirection which kills the overall idea of caching here while I want to keep data locality of the cache and index; I don't need the cache far away from index and this is the key here. Additionally, it increases index size which I want to avoid. If I am wrong, can you please sketch the way you implied to use it?

Comment: @DamirTenishev If you want more help on data layout you should make a separate question with details about your data and operations.

Comment: Are concepts available? Also, a side thought, perhaps we shouldn't dig into other class's guts (`index.data[0]`)  but have some getter `index.data()`, which wouldn't exist if there is no data at all

Comment: In the end it depends on the structure of your data. I think with the right design you have an indirection to the start of data which should be contiguous in memory and the cache friendliness will be there. And in an ECS that will not be a pointer in your struct. And no I cannot say ECS will be the best approach, I can only give hints. The end solution is always a tradeoff of many factors :)

Comment: @Aedoro, what kind of details would help? I have a large text compiled to lexems ids, index to this text as prefix array and make operations like search repeating sub-strings, repeating sub-stings with one or more lexems different, compare contexts of the lexems, etc. Something like [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/289260/fast-search-for-the-longest-repeating-substrings-in-large-text-rev-4). Very straightforward.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie, yes concepts available, I use the latest C++ functionality available in VS2022. Any ideas with it? The wrapper function helps and this is the way *Aedoro* suggested in his answer, but this again requires to use 'if constexpr' which is great, but sometimes transparency of my approach comes with significantly less price in terms of functions refactoring. And the key point is these lazy evaluations in `if` statements which I could lose if divide the conditions to the parts.

Comment: @PepijnKramer, on the "I think with the right design you have an indirection to the start of data which should be contiguous in memory and the cache friendliness will be there.", if you can sketch the idea in form of the code, I would be thankful. I can't see how indirection could help in avoiding cache issues while the whole idea of such caching is to keep the data next to the index.

Comment: No real ideas except that with Aedoro's way we could have a concept for empty one, and therefore an empty overload of template. both concepts and `if constexpr` obviosly work only in templates.  Wrong day for ideas , maybe. My brain revolves around what exists there https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus

Comment: Once you made the first indirection e.g the data in a vector the CPU "knows" where you are looking in memory. If after that the memory access pattern is predictable the CPU will start prefetching into cache lines. (A cache line is not something all too mysterious it is just  bit of memory in front and after the address). So the data in a std::vector is just such an example. You have one indirection to the allocated data and then you have a sequence of structs.

Comment: Whatever idea we have will still need to be profiled in practice to find the real bottlenecks, usually cache misses and branch prediction failures. The thing I think I missed so far in your question (maybe me bad) is that it seems you have information available at compile time.

Comment: @PepijnKramer, as it is stated in the question "The amount of cached data is compile-time choice", so, yes if you mean the cache size, it is known at compile time. If you mean something other with "information available", please, clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Similarly to your `static` member hack, but relying on compiler, since C++20, you might use attribute [`[[no_unique_address]]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/no_unique_address):

```
template<std::size_t _data_size>
struct ExtendableIndex
{
    std::size_t index;
    [[no_unique_address]] std::array<data_type, _data_size> data;
};
```

so `sizeof(ExtendableIndex<0>) == sizeof(std::size_t)` might be true, (but is not guaranteed :-/

You can ensure compiler support it as intended with `static_assert` it

```
static_assert(sizeof(ExtendableIndex<0>) == sizeof(std::size_t),
              "Compiler doesn't support [[no_unique_address]] as intended");
```

[EBO](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ebo) is guaranteed to some extends, and is generally more supported even for no-guaranteed case, so

```
template<std::size_t _data_size>
struct ExtendableIndex : private std::array<data_type, _data_size>
{
    std::size_t index;
    std::array<data_type, _data_size>& data() { return *this; }
    const std::array<data_type, _data_size>& data() const { return *this; }
};
```

Unfortunately, `std::array<T, 0>` implementations seems not compatible... You might probably provide your own `empty_array` to fix that.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately this [doesn't work](https://godbolt.org/z/73zEPaW8h) neither with CLang, nor with MSVC (even with `[[msvc::no_unique_address]]`)., but it works with [`char[]`](https://godbolt.org/z/YzEoGv75h). Most likely [[no_unique_address]] has to be used inside `std::array` to make it work, but if could be that there was no such attribute when `std::array` was developed. I will create a separate question on this.

Comment: Addressed the question in the comment above in the [Is it possible to use [[no_unique_address]] with non-POD types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78093066/is-it-possible-to-use-no-unique-address-with-non-pod-types)

Comment: Added EBO variant.