# Is it possible to use [[no_unique_address]] with non-POD types?

Tags: c++, std, c++-attributes

With the attribute `[[no_unique_address]]` used for plain old data (POD) arrays like `std::size_t[]` the template specialization for zero structure size could be as small as `index` member is has, not occupying memory for the `data` array.

When I do the same with the `std::array`, this doesn’t work. Most likely because `[[no_unique_address]]` it can’t handle compound object and this should have done in `std::array` implementation itself, but as I guess it was developed before `[[no_unique_address]]` attribute was introduced.

In case I need to have this `std::array` directly in the structure (no pointers, references, etc.) is there a chance to make `[[no_unique_address]]` working for `std::array` as it does for `std::size_t[]`?

Here is the [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/5fYe4Gozq)

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

using data_type = std::size_t;

template<std::size_t _data_size>
struct ExtendableIndexArray
{
    std::size_t index;
    [[no_unique_address]] std::array<data_type, _data_size> data;
 };

template<std::size_t _data_size>
struct ExtendableIndexPOD
{
    std::size_t index;
    [[no_unique_address]] data_type data[_data_size];
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Sizeof std::size_t = " << sizeof(std::size_t) << "\n\n";

    std::cout << "Sizeof ExtendableIndexPOD<0> = " << sizeof(ExtendableIndexPOD<0>) << '\n';
    std::cout << "Sizeof ExtendableIndexPOD<1> = " << sizeof(ExtendableIndexPOD<1>) << '\n';

    std::cout << '\n';

    std::cout << "Sizeof ExtendableIndexArray<0> = " << sizeof(ExtendableIndexArray<0>) << '\n';
    std::cout << "Sizeof ExtendableIndexArray<1> = " << sizeof(ExtendableIndexArray<1>) << '\n';
}
```

And the output:

```
Sizeof std::size_t = 8

Sizeof ExtendableIndexPOD<0> = 8
Sizeof ExtendableIndexPOD<1> = 16

Sizeof ExtendableIndexArray<0> = 16
Sizeof ExtendableIndexArray<1> = 16
```

Comment: [EBO](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ebo) works though [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/cW8PThnGT).

Comment: Notice that `data_type data[0]` is not valid, it is an extension.

Comment: @Jarod42, I can see how it works, it still prints `Sizeof ExtendableIndexArray<0> = 16` while I need `Sizeof ExtendableIndexArray<0> = 8` as in case with `data_type[]`.

Comment: `template<> struct ExtendableIndexPOD<0> { std::size_t index; };` is easiest workaround.  You can stick in a `struct Empty{}; [[no_unique_address]] Empty data;` if you need the `data` symbol.  You can add `operator[]` to Empty if you need a no-op index accessor.  (Same trick for either class, to get rid of the reliance on the extension.)

Comment: Implementation seems to have members even for `N==0` :-/ (making `[[no_unique_address]]`/EBO not available) ... So an `template <typename T, std::size_t N> using my_array = std::conditional_t<N == 0, my_empty_array<T>, std::array<T, N>>;` might fix that.

Comment: @Eljay, thank you. The `template<> struct ExtendableIndexPOD<0> { std::size_t index; }` is exactly what was used in the [original version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78092342/how-to-unify-access-to-class-member-when-their-presense-is-optional/), but current solution was proposed there, so I consider its usage. Trick with `Empty` works, thank you, although requires to mimic all the interface of `std::array` I use. And I am totally miss the point on the `operator[]` for Empty, could you please explain? What are "no-op index accessor" and "reliance on the extension"?

Comment: @Jarod42, on my comment above, I made a misprint with "I can see how it works"; I meant "I can't see how it works"; no kind of irony of harm was supposed; sorry for the typo.

Comment: @Jarod42, on the "Notice that data_type data[0] is not valid, it is an extension.", I refer to the "C99 6.7.2.1, §16: As a special case, the last element of a structure with more than one named member may have an incomplete array type; this is called a flexible array member."; for example here: [6.18 Arrays of Length Zero](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html).  I see that this is an extension, but I don't see any issues to use it exactly in this context.

Comment: @Jarod42, on the solution with `template <typename T, std::size_t N> using my_array = std::conditional_t<N == 0, my_empty_array<T>, std::array<T, N>>`, why do we need it? What it adds to template specialization used in the original question [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78092342/how-to-unify-access-to-class-member-when-their-presense-is-optional/)? It works automatically with the template specialization, what exactly this code adds?

Comment: If your code does `cout << x.data[5];` it won't compile.  But if you do `struct Empty { bool operator[](std::size_t) const { return false; }; };` the code will compile.  The "extension" being that in C++, the *flexible array member* isn't standard C++.  (Current C standard and current C++ standard continue to diverge.)

Comment: @Eljay, you mean when the ExtendableIndexPOD<0> template specialization is used? But this is exactly the case when I don't want `cout << x.data[5]` to be compiled since there is no element with index 5 in the array in this case. So, what could be the reason to use `operator[]` here?

Comment: In that case, if that is what you want at compile time, then do not provide an `operator[]`.  And if you do not want `x.data` to be allowed to be compiled, then do not provide `Empty data;`.

Comment: @Eljay, now I got your point. I just didn't have operations like `x.data[5]`, I had `x.begin()+5`, that's why I didn't get your point on this, assuming that you meant some general approach. Now I got your idea, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter to `[[no_unique_address]]` at all whether types are POD or not.

Also, `std::array` is almost surely a POD type if the element type is one.

The problem here is that 1. a built-in array of size `0` is not permitted in C++. If the compiler permits instantiation of `ExtendableIndexPOD<0>` without a diagnostic, then it is non-conforming to the ISO C++ standard (and neither to the ISO C standard). So arguing about the interaction with the ISO C++ feature `[[no_unique_address]]` without talking about a specific compiler is pointless.

And 2. there is no guarantee that `std::array` with size `0` as template parameter is implemented in such a way that the type will be empty (which is the only case in which `[[no_unique_address]]` can help with layout optimization).

And lastly, `[[no_unique_address]]` only *permits* the compiler to not give an empty object a unique address. Whether it will actually make that decision in order to reduce the size of the class is up to the compiler, or more specifically the ABI in use.

Comment: Thank you. Let me refer to the "C99 6.7.2.1, §16: As a special case, the last element of a structure with more than one named member may have an incomplete array type; this is called a flexible array member."; for example here: [6.18 Arrays of Length Zero](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html). I see that this is an extension, but I don't see any issues to use it exactly in this context.

Comment: @DamirTenishev That doesn't apply to ISO C++ and is not a feature that is compatible with ISO C++. Also that rule requires an _incomplete_ array type, i.e. `int member[];`, not `int member[0];`. The latter is not valid in C99 either, but some compilers have it as a non-conforming extension from before C99 introduced the flexible array members.

Comment: @DamirTenishev "_but I don't see any issues to use it exactly in this context._": It is non-obvious how a flexible array member would interact with `[[no_unique_address]]` and since no standard considers both features in conjunction, there is no way to be sure about the result. The problem is that you'll be relying on what the specific compiler decided to do (and hopefully the compiler developers made a deliberate and documented choice).

Comment: The [6.18 Arrays of Length Zero](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html) shows as the first example the code with `char contents[0];`. The question is that people and compiler say that this is an extension for C++ and I can't see what does it mean. What is "an extension"? We have the standard and I see at least per SO 9899:2011 6.7.6.2: *If the expression is a constant expression, it shall have a value greater than zero.* which refers to arrays in the §1, as well, so I understand this. But what is "an extension", then?

Comment: So, are you saying that the answer to the question itself "this is impossible at all for any type"?

Comment: @DamirTenishev It is meant as an extension in the sense that it is a modification of the languages that extents the range of valid programs with defined meaning. Technically as I wrote, having this "extension" enabled without any warnings causes the compiler to be non-conforming to the standard per the rule you quoted.

Comment: @DamirTenishev What exactly is impossible? The issue is just an arbitrary choice by the library implementer of `std::array`. You could implement your own `std::array` that is an empty class if the specified size is `0` and then you could use it as you do `std::array` now and, assuming the ABI specification doesn't say anything else, the compiler will be able to do the optimization as you intent.

Comment: @DamirTenishev In principle you could also ask the library author to improve their `std::array` implementation, but they are unlikely to do so, because that would be breaking the library ABI.